# Ajuste Lineal simple y multiple, duda con sus graficas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, regresión-lineal

Tengo las variables `x` e `y` que seran mis variables independientes y dependiente.

Se pide:

- Usar `x` como regresor.
- Usar x^2
- Finalmente usar regresion lineal multiple con x y x^ como regresores.

Debo calcular los **coeficientes** de regresión así como el error cuadrático medio. **Debo gráficar** estos ajustes en una misma gráfica con los datos originales, **eso es lo que mas duda me genera**. Estos son los datos y el código.

```
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

N=50
indep_vars = np.random.uniform(size = N, low = 0, high = 10)
r = np.random.normal(size = N, loc = 0.0, scale = 8.0)
dep_vars = 2 + 3*indep_vars + 2*indep_vars**2 + r

x = indep_vars.reshape(-1,1)#Variable x, regresor.
   
xc = x**2
y = dep_vars
X = np.concatenate((x,xc),axis=1)
lm = LinearRegression()#creamos el modelo
lm.fit(x,y)#ajustamos
yl_predict = lm.intercept_ + lm.coef_ * x
errores = y-yl_predict
print("ECM para regresor x:",(errores**2).mean())

#utilizamos x^ como regresor.
lm.fit(xc,y)
ylc_predict = lm.intercept_ + lm.coef_ * x**2
errores = y-ylc_predict
print("ECM para regresor x^:",(errores**2).mean())

##utilizamos dos regresores- x y x^^-
lm.fit(X,y)
yml_predict = lm.predict(X)
errores = y - yml_predict
print("ECM para regresores x y x^:",(errores**2).mean())
```

Para las gráficas intente algo asi, pero no se ve muy bien **¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se vea mejor**?:

```
#plt.scatter(indep_vars,dep_vars)
#plt.plot(x,yl_predict,c="green")
#plt.plot(x,ylc_predict,c="red")
#plt.plot(x,yml_predict,color="blue")
```

A lo que queria llegar era algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe aclarar que esta grafica corresponde a los mismos datos pero para el ajuste no se uso el modulo LinearRegresion sino una funcion cuyo codigo adjunto:

```
def ajuste_lineal_simple(x,y):
    a = sum(((x - x.mean())*(y-y.mean()))) / sum(((x-x.mean())**2))
    b = y.mean() - a*x.mean()
    return a, b

xc = x**2
ap, bp = ajuste_lineal_simple(xc, y)
grilla_y_p = (grilla_x**2)*ap + bp
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(grilla_x, grilla_y, c = 'green')
plt.plot(grilla_x, grilla_y_p, c = 'red')
plt.title('ajuste lineal con x^2')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola Sebastian! lo primero que puedes hacer es limpiar el código, no tiene sentido hacer `yl_predict = lm.intercept_ + lm.coef_ * x` y después hacer
`errores = y-lm.predict(x)`, ya que cuando multiplicas las betas más el intercepto a tus variables, estás prediciendo, por lo que escoge un método u otro. Además también pondría las importaciones que estás haciendo.

Comment: Hola Alberto gracias, tienes razon, en verdad puede simplificarse el codigo ahora que lo veo. Estos son los modulo que use en este codigo :          
pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Comment: Genial, puedes darle al boton de editar e incluirlo en la pregunta, tienes mi respuesta abajo, no sé si te a servido.

Comment: SI, lo acabo de editar, gracias por la recomendacion. Vi tu respuestas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Vi que hiciste dos plots separados, yo intentaba que queden todos en la misma grafica, de hecho lo hice pero no se ven nada bien, seguramente estoy equivocandome en algo pero no se en que. Voy a mostrarte una imagen que vi donde las graficas estan juntas y a lo que queria llegar, editare mi codigo para incluir esto al final.

Comment: Sebastian, es lo que te indico en la respuesta, es imposible que quede bien en una sola gráfica, porque el eje de las X es 10 y en otro es 100, luego una linea, solo va a llegar hasta el 10 y otra se va a ir hasta el 100. Y la tercera gráfica es una regresión lineal multiple de 3 dimensiones, por lo que es físicamente imposible representar 3 dimensiones en un espacio de dos dimensiones. Por otro lado, gracias por incluir los imports en la pregunta :)

Comment: Gracias Alberto por la ayuda y por el tiempo. Tratare de avanzar y no estancarme.

Comment: De nada, como consejo para el sitio, lo mejor es que postees una duda concreta y específica, si pones varias es difícil de ayudar. Con la última actualización que has puesto de la foto no puedes usar una regresión lineal, porque la regresión lineal como su nombre indica es una recta, no una parabola, por tanto pretendes otra cosa a la incialmente planteada. Siento no haberte podido resolver el problema.